# pgfplots/pics/apple silicon/error

Tags: tikz-pgf

When executing the minimal example below, Pgfplots is informing the following error ``Package pgf Error: No shape named `B1' is known.''

The compilation is done via 2024 mactex running in a macbook pro with apple silicon. Not sure whether the processor architecture or the tex distribution or other is the cause of the problem. When compiling in a macbook pro with an Intel processor and 2021 mactex distribution the code works. Any ideas or help to address this problem?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\tikzset{bus/.pic={
\draw[fill] (-0.7,-0.05) rectangle (0.7,0.05);
}}

%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[scale = 0.5, rotate=90] (B1) at (0,0)  {bus};
\pic[scale = 0.5, rotate=90]  (B2)  at (4,0) {bus};
\draw (B1) -- (B2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. There is a syntax error, you are confusing it with node. The prefix must be indicated in the `pic` creation code to be able to use it later.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my problem and accepted your answer.  Out of curiosity, is there a way to make a pic object behave like a node to simple instruct "\draw (B1) -- (B2)", i.e., without the prefix -center, for automatic interconnection? Internally, I am still wondering why I do not have this error in my Intel system.

Comment: No, as specified in the manual `Unlike nodes, pics cannot be referenced later on. You can reference nodes that are inside a pic, but not “the pic itself”.` Like the `\coordinate` command creates a `node`, that's why it can be accessed in the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error, you are confusing it with node. The prefix must be indicated in the pic creation code to be able to use it later.

Here is an example that allows you to access the pic.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\tikzset{bus/.pic={
\draw[fill] (-0.7,-0.05) rectangle (0.7,0.05);
 % prefix which allows access to the pic
\coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
}}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic [scale = 0.5, rotate=90] (B1) at (0,0)  {bus};
\pic [scale = 0.5, rotate=90] (B2)  at (4,0) {bus};
\draw (B1-center) -- (B2-center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```